# Javascript to a php handler page using htaccess

Tags: php, javascript, apache, .htaccess

My attempt to do this is...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule \.js$ js.php [L]   ## This line is the one I tried to add
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

If I use a tag `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.domain.net/myfile.js'></script>` I would like it to go through `js.php`.

**js.php**
Will handle the file using `header('....'); echo file_get_contents('myfile.js');`

I have tried so many things to do this, I had done this before on a project but I can't remember where now as I have to redo it :)

Hope it makes sense...

Comment: Have you your myfile.js accessible from http://www.domain.net/myfile.js ? Actually the rule RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f says that if the file is accessible then it has to be served. If this files does not exists then other rules will be applied.

Comment: I still need that for images though... or other files like PDF,MP3, etc..

Comment: @fsehat these rules are below \.js rule and it has [L] modifier.

Comment: @Val have you tried `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js$ /js.php [L]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the following rewrite rule :

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)\.js$ js.php [NC,L]
```

In place of :

```
RewriteRule \.js$ js.php [L]   ## This line is the one I tried to add
```

The result is :

```
http://www.domain.net/myfile.js => http://www.domain.net/js.php
http://www.domain.net/foo/bar/myfile.js => http://www.domain.net/js.php
```

Or you can do as follows :

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)\.js$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

The result is :

```
http://www.domain.net/myfile.js => http://www.domain.net/myfile.php
http://www.domain.net/foo/bar/myfile.js => http://www.domain.net/foo/bar/myfile.php
```

Some explanations about used [RewriteRule flags](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/rewrite/flags.html) :

- [NC](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_nc) : Use of the [NC] flag causes the RewriteRule to be matched in a case-insensitive manner. That is, it doesn't care whether letters appear as upper-case or lower-case in the matched URI.
- [L](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) : The [L] flag causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set. In most contexts, this means that if the rule matches, no further rules will be processed. This corresponds to the last command in Perl, or the break command in C. Use this flag to indicate that the current rule should be applied immediately without considering further rules.

Comment: This worked for me :) can you update your answer with the definition of terms `[NC,L]` so I know what it means.

Comment: sweeet, It makes sense :) thumbs up